# shape intrinsic function in fortran

Tags: matlab, fortran, gfortran

I am playing around with the `shape()` intrinsic function in fortran:

```
program test

    integer, dimension(5,3) :: A
    integer, dimension(2) :: ShapeA

    ShapeA = shape(A)
    print *, ShapeA(1)
    print *, ShapeA(2)
end program test
```

I understand the `shape` function returns a 2 element vector containing the length and width of array `A`. In the above code, the output of `shape(A)` is passed to the predefined variable `ShapeA`. Then the contents of `ShapeA` are printed out, namely 5 and 3.

I would like to find a way to refer to the contents of the output of `shape(A)` without having to assign it to an intermediate variable `ShapeA`.

This would be similar to the matlab `size` function which enables looping constructs like this:

```
A =  [1 2 3 5 4; 2 3 5 4 5]

for i = 1:size(A,2)
    A(2,i)
end
```

Which means the user need not assign another variable like so:

```
A =  [1 2 3 5 4; 2 3 5 4 5]
sizeA = size(A,2)

for i = 1:sizeA
    A(2,i)
end
```

In fortran it is necessary to both declare the variable, assign it a value using `size` statement then include that variable in the loop. I would like to remove the first two steps and see if it can be done like in matlab. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps [`size`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SIZE.html)?

Comment: If it is size in Matlab, why not try size in Fortran? And why not read some Fortran manual?

Comment: Unfortunately `size` gives the total number of elements in `A`. For example in this case it would equal 15. This would not be helpful in my situation since I am trying to isolate the values for length and width of `A`. I will edit my question to make it more clear

Comment: It was clear enough, size is still what you want

Comment: @VladimirF. I am in a fast paced office environment right now. I think opening up a fortran manual and reading it like a novel would be quite ludicrous...

Comment: Luckily it's online

Comment: Noone reads a manual like a novel. Google the shape intrinsic, look at related functions and size is one of them. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SHAPE.html BTW I did not vote here in any way so someone probably agrees with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the fortran manual page for shape there is a link to [`SIZE`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SIZE.html), specifically (emphasis mine)

> Description:
>
> Determine the extent of ARRAY **along a specified dimension DIM**, or the total number of elements in ARRAY if DIM is absent.

```
program test

    integer, dimension(5,3) :: A

    print *, size(A,1)
    print *, size(A,2)
end program test
```

Comment: Ok so basically its almost exactly like Matlab. Thank you very much. The Fortran docs can be hard to read sometimes.

Comment: @user32882 I have rarely come up with a Fortran question that is not answered fully in "Modern Fortran Explained" of Metcalf et al. For the `shape()` function refer to page 176 therein: https://books.google.com/books/about/Modern_Fortran_Explained.html?id=V7UVDAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button#v=onepage&q&f=false